# MongoDB CREATE SCHEMA equivalent

Tags: mongodb, namespaces

In SQL databases such as postgres, we can CREATE SCHEMA  so we can reference our tables as schema_name.table_name. Are there schemas in mongodb? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MongoDB, there are databases, collections and documents. These are analogous to database, table and row in a SQL/RDBMS (e.g., MySQL database). Each document has fields and their values - like in a JSON.

See [Databases and Collections](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/databases-and-collections/), and [Documents](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/).

There is no equivalent to a SQL/RDBMS Schema in MongoDB.

There is something called as [Schema Validation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/schema-validation/) - and this is not related the Schema you are referring to. This allows validation rules for the document fields during *update* and *insert* operations. For example, a field is required. Schema Validation is used optionally.